# DEP Enrollment with Virtual Machines

Tags: parallels-desktop, virtualbox, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

I have a company-provided 2019 MacBook Pro that is enrolled in Apple DEP and has Jamf as the MDM provider. (OS Version is Big Sur, 11.6.2)

For a side project I created several virtual machines with Parallels and VirtualBox and it quickly turned into another kind of endeavour:

With VirtualBox, the OS setup never gets to the "remote management" step, just goes on like a generic Mac. But with Parallels, no matter what I do (in terms of configuration), it is always stuck at the "remote management" step. (Which I don't want.) I mean, I can opt into it with my VM but the setup won't let me go without it. This is never the case with VirtualBox.

This ingrigued me and I have been experimenting and researching about it. Because I am kind of new to the Apple world and want to learn more about it.

**Question:** How is this even possible? How does the VM (in Parallels) get aware of its outside world and is able to introduce itself (specifically) to my company's MDM server and more importantly how come there is no way to isolate the VM from the company?

#### Details:

- I tried the OS installations with (what I believe to be) a clean ISO. Grabbed it from App Store and extracted the ISO using createinstallmedia utility through CLI.
- In Parallels, actually, the VM is not readily able to grab the MDM profiles from the server. To obtain them, the machine must have a registered serial number and a correct device id, both of which are configurable within Parallels. During my research, I also verified this is really the case with Apple DEP. But this also means the virtual machine, by default, just has a generic serial number, yet it still able to identify itself with my company. (i.e. Requires the remote management step to be fulfilled.)

Comment: AD works better with one question at a time. You may want to edit your question down to focus it better and then you can open another question or two if you still need it.

Comment: @SteveChambers: Thank you for taking the time to leave a comment. I had felt that the questions are quite related to each other and thus included them together. I will think about how I can make it more specific.

Comment: Instead of listing assumptions and intermediate questions, can you focus on the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I think #1 is your actual question. Your second and third question are probing at that one. I hope you do take the time to edit this as it’s something I’m curious about too!

Comment: ...also, shot in the dark—if you go to About This Mac in Parallels, does it show the same serial number as the host computer? What about in other VM’s? Depending on results, that could explain what’s going on, I’m pretty sure DEP is serial number based.

Comment: I made some adjustments and requested a review. However, with all due respect @nohillside, I am still finding it hard to understand how these intermingled questions deserved their own separate pages. (It could be my mistake to assume a similar culture here in AD as in SO which I frequent. In fact, a quick look at the community guidelines, just now, has made me think so.)

Comment: @wowfunhappy: Actually, you are right. I have never had a chance to enter into the OS with a Parallels VM and thus check the actual serial number. I'll try doing that BEFORE setup. Otherwise, no way to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I can't speak for other SE sites, but what usually happens with posts containing multiple questions on AD is that you end up getting partial answers focusing on different sub-questions, with a lot of discussions in the comment because none of the answers is complete. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so we prefer focused questions related to practical problems you want to solve.

Comment: Just checked - a Parallels VM *does* inherit the serial number of the Mac it's running on [even if the VM wasn't originally set up on that Mac, but copied from another.] Voted to reopen, because the mechanics of DEP enforcement intrigue me

Comment: I second @Tetsujin, created a new VM from scratch and just before starting the installation, when I had the chance, I took a look at the serial number through Terminal: `ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber` It is indeed the serial number of the physical machine.

I'd like to convert this to a proper answer if the question gets reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ANSWER

The reason is that Parallels VMs, by default, use the serial number of the physical machine they are running on, even if they are created on a different machine. Therefore, during OS installation, the installer contacts Apple with a real-world DEP-enrolled serial number. (While in VirtualBox the serial number is 0.) **This results in DEP enforcement!**

There is another parameter involved during installation, though, and it is the "model identifier" and Parallels do not copy it. Therefore, despite being DEP enrolled and enforced at this stage of the installation, the setup cannot continue because the MDM provider (Jamf, here) refuses to serve the machine with the profile because of the model identifier mismatch.

### SOLUTION

Solution is to set those two parameters manually for your desired outcome. If you want DEP enrollment, you need a real, registered serial number and a corresponding model identifier. If you **DO NOT** want to enroll with DEP but want a clean, generic MacOS installation (which was my original goal), then you need to change your serial number to a non-registered one.

[Detailed Instructions for Manipulating Serial Number in Parallels](https://kb.parallels.com/en/123455) 
[Instructions for Enrollment with a Parallels VM](https://kb.parallels.com/en/124564)

### IMPORTANT NOTE

Interestingly, staying offline during setup also gets you out of DEP enrollment. But that was not what I wanted.

### Appendix

If you want to check for the parameters, for yourself:

> Serial Number
> `ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber`

> Model Identifier
> `sysctl hw.model`

> System information utility shows the two fields in hardware overview tab under their exact names.